# Save changes on WooCommerce Admin Settings

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get the form data on save changes button for validation.

I used `WC_Admin_Settings::save_fields( $settings );` to save the form fields where `$settings` have username and password text arrays but before saving I need to get the username and password for verification and if it matches then save else show error message.